# input and output device of sound is suspended

Tags: sound, 22.04, pipewire

I am Running

```
   Distributor ID:  Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
    Release:    22.04
     Codename:  jammy
```

hardware is

```
 Terminal: gnome-terminal 
Intel CPU: Intel i5-8250U (8) @ 3.400GHz 
GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 620 
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445 / 
530/535 / 620/625 Mobile
```

my input and output device of sound  is suspended

```
46  alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor  PipeWire    s32le 2ch 48000Hz    
SUSPENDED
  47    alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo   PipeWire    s32le 2ch 48000Hz   
SUSPENDED
 115    NoiseTorch Microphone for Built-in Audio    PipeWire    float32le 1ch 48000Hz    
SUSPENDED
```

how I can run this